# Insert Text 2 lines above Pattern

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have some C code from a codegenerator and have to insert a line two lines before a specific mark in the code.

Example, generated Code: `file.c`

```
void foo () {
  bar();
}

# <- I want a line to be added here!
void example () {
  MARKERFUNCTION();
  ...
}
```

I do not know the exact position of `MARKERFUNCTION()` but it appears only once in the file and is the first line in `example()`. `example()` is not a fixed name.

A single sed command would be great, but a combination of grep and something else would do too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed '/()\s*{/{N; s/.*MARKERFUNCTION/== Text to add ==\n\0/}' file.c 
void foo () {
  bar();
}

== Text to add ==
void example () {
  MARKERFUNCTION();
  ...
}
```

- `/()\s*{/` match `()` followed by any spaces and `{` - to detect line with function.. if there can be content inside `()`, using `/)\s*{/` could work
- `{N;` if above condition matches, get next line
- `s/.*MARKERFUNCTION/== Text to add ==\n\0/` perform substitution by checking if the pattern `MARKERFUNCTION` is there in the two lines we have. Then in replacement section, add the required text, a newline and the pattern matched which by default is in `\0`

`awk` solution, assuming there is a blank line prior to start of function having the required pattern

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '/MARKERFUNCTION/{$0 = "--Text to add--\n" $0} 1' file.c
void foo () {
  bar();
}

--Text to add--
void example () {
  MARKERFUNCTION();
  ...
}
```

This reads the input file paragraph wise and if a paragraph contains the required pattern, add a line before printing

Comment: Not attempting with `perl` this time around :) ?

Comment: @Inian, sed seemed tailor made for this case and my experience has been that using perl as a command is not favored by most :-/

Comment: The sed line was exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Using `tac` with `awk`:

```
tac file.c | awk '/MARKERFUNCTION/{p=NR} p && NR==p+2{print "new line added"} 1' | tac

void foo () {
  bar();
}

# <- I want a line to be added here!
new line added
void example () {
  MARKERFUNCTION();
  ...
}
```

Comment: fyi: I think you didn't realize that this is adding the text to last but one line as well...

Comment: Funny Idea using tac